# Check if record exist in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Below is the snippet of firebase database named Users.

```
Users
- XXzEdCWHDJDHJ9AjcvdBWiGaqzI12(unique UserId)
   - name : test1
   - userType: parent

- XXzEdCWIOOVB9tgfdgdfgdgdgf12
   - name : test2
   - userType: teacher 

- XXzEddfdsfsdfdsfsdBWiGaqzI12
   - name : test3
   - userType: student
```

Is there any way to check if child with userType student exist in Users?

Comment: Yes, you can query the database with a filter: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data

Comment: @DougStevenson yeah, use filter is the way